# Looking for a github project that represents Rails best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a Rails project on github that demonstrates best practices for writing a Rails application. Could anyone recommend one?

Answer (score 3):

Spot-us (developed by Hashrocket) provides a lot of useful best practices, like high test coverage, restful design, etc.
You can find the source on [github](http://github.com/spot-us/spot-us).

(No, I'm not a Hashrocket employee)

Answer (score 2):

You could start looking at some of the available skeleton apps, which are application templates ready to start hacking on them:

- [Bort](http://jimneath.org/2008/09/09/bort-base-rails-application.html)
- [suspenders](http://giantrobots.thoughtbot.com/2008/10/21/suspenders)
- [Starter-app](https://github.com/patmaddox/starter-app)
- appstarter

Studying them should give you a grasp of up-to-date best practices.

Comment: None of those links are up-to-date